# Executing sudo commands without password, not using /etc/sudoers?

Tags: sudo, privileges

I've created an instance of Ubuntu 20.04 in Azure, and I've noticed that I can run sudo commands without typing a password.

I assumed that this is done by using the `NOPASSWD` directive in the `/etc/sudoers` file, but this file is completely standard and doesn't include this directive.

Can someone tell if there's any other way this can be achieved?

The /etc/sudoers file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: @Bodo, anyways, no, there's no password for the user, but I've also tried creating a user with no password and it did ask for a password for this user..

Comment: Do you have any files in `/etc/sudoers.d`?

Comment: Apparently I have, thanks :)